# How does one remove a button element from the DOM after it was clicked?

Tags: javascript, dom, button, events

I want to make my button delete itsself on click,I already tried this:

```js
var myArray = ['JavaScript is awesome', 'Pacific coffe is really delicious', 'This is a fancy website'];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("newQuote");


function showquote() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("quote").innerHTML = myArray[rand]);
  button.remove();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>
<p class="quote"></p>
<button class="newQuote" onclick="showquote()">Generate Quote</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```

still nothing works,please help

Comment: from/with all the provided answers, are there any questions left?

Comment: It was nice if the OP gives some feedback to any of the plenty provided answers and/or makes use of the button which accepts the to the OP most useful one. Dropping a question, getting help, but not providing feedback is not the most polite behavior. Maybe you have some time as much as all of the answerers had it for you.

Answer (score 0):

`button` is an array just write `button[0].remove();`

```js
var myArray = ['JavaScript is awesome', 'Pacific coffe is really delicious', 'This is a fancy website'];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("newQuote");


function showquote(){
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("newQuote").innerHTML = myArray[rand]);
   button[0].remove()
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<p class="quote"></p>
<button class ="newQuote"onclick="showquote()">Generate Quote</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>


<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.remove()` is a jQuery method. But you are selecting your button with vanilla Javascript (`document.getElementsByClassName("newQuote")`) so it doesn't have any jQuery method. Besides, `getElementsByClassName` returns a *list* of elements, not one element, so you have to iterate them.

Solution : use jQuery to select your button.

Also, why use inline JS (`onclick="showquote()"`)? Use a jQuery click handler.

```js
var button = $(".newQuote");
button.click(showquote);

function showquote() {
  button.remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="quote"></p>
<button class="newQuote">Generate Quote</button>
```

Comment: [*"The `ChildNode.remove()` method removes the object from the tree it belongs to."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove). The OP's problem on that matter was that `button = document.getElementsByClassName("newQuote");` does not assign an `HTMLElement` to `button` but an `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: Yes, I just learned that indeed. And another solution, since OP loads jQuery anyway, is to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

The OP's main problem with [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)ing a button is that ...

```
button = document.getElementsByClassName("newQuote");
```

... does not assign an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) to `button` but an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) ... have a look at [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

One might think about having an easier or more generic way of accessing an element which did trigger a certain event.

A reliable way is to register events via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of relying on the OP's original inline event handling. Then one either uses the [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) of an event-handler's [`Event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#properties) or one uses [the handler's `this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler) which also represent the triggering event target.

```js
var myArray = [
  'JavaScript is awesome',
  'Pacific coffe is really delicious',
  'This is a fancy website',
];

function addQuote(evt) {
  const btnElm = evt.currentTarget;
//const btnElm = this; // this variant is equally fine.

  document
    .querySelector('.quote')
    .textContent += ' - ' + myArray[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)
    ];

  btnElm.remove();
};

function init() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.newQuote')
    .forEach(elmNode =>
      elmNode.addEventListener('click', addQuote)
    );
}

init();
```

```html
<button class ="newQuote">Generate a quote</button>
<button class ="newQuote">Generate another quote</button>
<button class ="newQuote">Generate yet another quote</button>

<p class="quote"></p>
```